# Bypassing authentication for localhost in order to implement search in Etherpad

Tags: javascript, authentication, solr, nutch, etherpad

I'm trying to implement Nutch + Solr based search engine into my Etherpad installation. The main issue I'm having is that Nutch doesn't support `POST` authentication. Etherpad and Nutch are installed on the same machine, so an obvious solution would be to find a way to bypass authentication for `localhost`.

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know the Etherpad codebase very well, I've mostly done cosmetic tweaks until now.

Can someone point me to where I should be looking, or potential solutions ? I've found some interesting bits of code having do to with auth in the codebase, but it's Javascript, so there's no obvious way to check if the request host is `localhost`.

Edit :

I've found the code that handles the auth policy, and tested it with a simple condition so that it always returns `true`. Authentication can then be bypassed. Which leaves me with my initial problem : how can I determine if the host is `localhost` in Javascript ?

```
 if (guestPolicy == "allow") {
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which leaves me with my initial problem : how can I determine if the host is localhost in Javascript ?

Use the `location` API:

```
if (/localhost/.test(location.hostname) )
```

**References**

- [MSDN: location Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535866)